# XMLHttpRequestError issue when signing up user using parse

Tags: javascript, parsing, authentication

I'm trying to use Parse.com to sign users up to my application I'm developing. However I seem to get an error when firing my function.

```
Parse.initialize("APP ID", "JS KEY");

function signUp() {
    var user = new Parse.User();

    // Get user inputs from form.
    var username = document.login.username.value;
    var password = document.login.password.value;

    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("password", password);
    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function (user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

The error:

```
Error: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}
```

Any help here would be great, i'm unsure what's causing the error. Seems to work correctly when i'm not passing form data through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you instead should use:

```
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(password);
```

Also, these can be combined:

```
Parse.User.signUp(username, password, { ACL: new Parse.ACL() }, {
    success: function (user) {
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```